# Counting number of ids present in one table which is not presented on another for a particular user

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, php

I have two tables I want to count the number of ids presented on first which is not in second with respect to user id how can I do the same?

For example.

**Case 1**

Table 1.

```
|id|data           |User_id
|4 |Some data      |12
|5 |Another data   |8
|6 |Some other data|6
```

Table2

```
|id|table1Id|userId|
|1 |4       |12    |
|2 |5       |14    |
|3 |12      |12    |
```

**Case 2**

Table 1.

```
|id|data           |userid
|4 |Some data      |12
|5 |Another data   |24
|6 |Some other data|32
|7 |Some more data |12
```

Table2

```
|id|table1Id|userId|
|1 |4       |12    |
|2 |5       |14    |
|3 |12      |12    |
```

What I am trying to do is this.

**I want to know how many occurrences of id in table1 which is not in table2  for the user 12.**

How can I do that?

**Case 1 it should return 0**

**Case2 it should return 1**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it by using **`NOT EXISTS`**

First example:

> ```
> create table table1 (id int, data varchar(100), user_id int);
> insert into table1 values (4, 'some data', 12);
> insert into table1 values (5, 'another data', 8);
> insert into table1 values (6, 'some another data', 6);
> create table table2 (id int, tableid int, user_id int);
> insert into table2 values (1, 4, 12);
> insert into table2 values (2, 5, 14);
> insert into table2 values (3, 12, 12);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT count(*) coincidences
> FROM   table1
> WHERE  user_id = 12
> AND    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
>                    FROM   table2
>                    WHERE  tableid = table1.id
>                    AND    user_id = table1.user_id);
> ```
>
> ```
> | coincidences |
> | -----------: |
> |            0 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=a744a1b5c07ee0c886506139f154f75f)*

Second example:

> ```
> create table table1 (id int, data varchar(100), user_id int);
> insert into table1 values (4, 'some data', 12);
> insert into table1 values (5, 'another data', 24);
> insert into table1 values (6, 'some another data', 32);
> insert into table1 values (7, 'some more data', 12);
> create table table2 (id int, tableid int, user_id int);
> insert into table2 values (1, 4, 12);
> insert into table2 values (2, 5, 14);
> insert into table2 values (3, 12, 12);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT count(*) coincidences
> FROM   table1
> WHERE  user_id = 12
> AND    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
>                    FROM   table2
>                    WHERE  tableid = table1.id
>                    AND    user_id = table1.user_id)
> ```
>
> ```
> | coincidences |
> | -----------: |
> |            1 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=077365e59695fdcc482fed218fdfa650)*

Comment: I am seeing this query is very slow for the comparatively bigger table is there a way to rewrite the same with JOIN operations I have tried some but failed.

Comment: Which MySql version?

Comment: @AndriyM Is that in at this way Instead of this    FROM   table2
                   WHERE  tableid = table1.id
                   AND    user_id = table1.user_id) This one? FROM   table2
                   WHERE  tableid,user_id = table1.id
                   AND    user_id = table1.user_id)

Comment: @McNets  Mysql 5.6

Comment: @arunwebber: No, the condition used in the answer is correct as it is. It has already been updated from `WHERE tableid = table1.id` (correlation on `tableid` only) to `WHERE tableid = table1.id AND user_id = table1.user_id` (correlation on both `tableid` and `user_id`).

Comment: @AndriyM The first query was faster than the rewritten query. from my end

Comment: @arunwebber: The rewritten one is more accurate though. Normally you are supposed to first get the results right, then tune the performance.

Comment: @AndriyM I got the answer but the only problem is that it is taking almost 4 sec to execute user will die because of boredom :( Any way thank you thanks a lot

Comment: @arunwebber: Feel free to ask a new question about improving the performance of this solution.

Comment: @AndriyM Question has asked here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193324/following-mysql-query-is-too-much-time