# Following mysql query is taking too much time for excecution

Tags: mysql-5.6

I have a MySQL table which is described in the following question.
[Counting number of ids present in one table which is not presented on another for a particular user](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193119/counting-number-of-ids-present-in-one-table-which-is-not-presented-on-another-fo)
The query which I am using is as follows.

```
SELECT count(*) coincidences
FROM   table1
WHERE  user_id = 12
AND    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   table2
                   WHERE  tableid = table1.id
                   AND    user_id = table1.user_id)
```

This query is taking too much time for considerably bigger table how can I improve the performance of this particular query.

Answer (score 1):

`table2` needs `INDEX(tableid, user_id)` (in either order).

If this does not solve the problem, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables, plus `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.